# Initialization of custom object return null

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios6

Here is my custom class:

ClassA.h

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject<RKRequestDelegate>{
    NSString *uri;
    NSString *folderUri;
    NSInteger idFolder;
    NSString *kind;
    bool isMine;

    CustomUser *owner;

    NSMutableArray *usersAdministrators;
    NSMutableArray *usersContributors;
    NSMutableArray *usersReaders;

    NSString *visibility;
    NSString *name;
    NSString *description;

    NSMutableArray *comments;
}


@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *uri;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *folderUri;
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSInteger idFolder;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *kind;
@property (nonatomic,assign) bool isMine;

@property (retain) DMIUser *owner;

@property (nonatomic,copy) NSMutableArray *usersAdministrators;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSMutableArray *usersContributors;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSMutableArray *usersReaders;

@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *visibility;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *description;

@property (nonatomic,copy) NSMutableArray *comments;


@end
```

ClassA.m

```
@implementation ClassA
@synthesize uri,folderUri,idFolder,kind,isMine,owner,usersAdministrators,usersContributors,usersReaders,visibility,name,description,comments;

-(NSString*)description {
    return @"ClassA";
}


@end
```

Quite simple. But when i try to create new instance of this, like this:

```
datas = [NSMutableArray array]; // Tried with [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] => same thing
ClassA *classA = [[ClassA alloc] init];
[datas addObject:classA];
NSLog(@"classA = %@",classA);
NSLog(@"datas = %@",datas);
```

First NSLog returns "ClassA". 
Second NSLog returns "datas = ()"

What's wrong here? I always created class like this and i've never had problem like this.
Thanks!

Comment: are you sure about that? you really can see in logs string like: "classA = nil description" ?? cause basically thats just impossible

Comment: Yes yes, it say "*nil description*". First time i see it also.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057240/why-is-my-code-outputting-nil-description

Comment: @ApheX See the duplicate question that Anoop Vaidya referenced. The implementation of you `description` method is incomplete.

Comment: I updated with full code. Description method seems to work, but why? This is the first time i need to put it. Anyway, if i try to put my object into an array, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guyzzz i found the problem. It's my attribute:

```
NSString *description;
```

Seems that iOs doesn't love that. It conflict with the -description method in NSObject...
After that, i found a similar question here:
[Why can't I use "description" as an attribute name for a Core Data entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717519/why-cant-i-use-description-as-an-attribute-name-for-a-core-data-entity)

Cheers

Comment: Next time, post your real code so we can help better, glad you found your solution though!

Comment: I do not imagined for a moment that it could be caused by attribute name...
Anyway thanks for advice :)

Answer (score 0):

if your want to return some value implement method description in the ClassA

```
- (NSString *)description {

     return @"ClassA";

}
```

Comment: He should still be getting an address printed out like ClassA = <ClassA: 0x1001082b0>

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Anyway, my object is alredy null:
If i try to put it in an NSMutableArray, i can see it's null.

Comment: @ApheX No, your object is not null. When you log an array, the `description` method of every object is called. So you see the same "nil description" that you see when logging your object directly.

Comment: @maddy i edited my question with full code. See at NSLog return. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You've got everything you need. Are you sure the variable you're assigning to isn't a weak one? All delegate properties are weak, therefore not retaining the object. My guess is that you're doing something like this

```
someObject.delegate = [[ClassA alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@", someObject.delegate);
```

Because the delegate property is `weak` it doesn't hold onto the variable.

Edit: 
This whole answer assumes you are using ARC. If not, disregard.

Comment: this is his code, ClassA *classA = [[ClassA alloc] init];
NSLog(@"classA = %@",classA); no use of talking about weak and delegates right ?

Comment: his object does implement <RKRequestDelegate> so I thought that was a valuable clue. I'm pretty sure the code he provided was just an example and not his real code.

Comment: Anyway, with or without <RKRequestDelegate>, it doesn't work.